# When to use sort By clause in hive QL

Tags: hiveql

I checked the difference between sort by vs order by clause in hive. 
Order by used when total ordering is required while sort by is used when there are multiple reducer & input to reducer required to be in sorted order. Hence sort by could lead to total order if there is only one reducer & partial ordering if there are multiple reducer-

Ref- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy

My question is when do we need to use sort by clause in hiveQL ?

Answer (score 0):

when the data is sorted then joins are faster since optimizer is aware that data is sorted in specific order & after which value it needs to stop looking for required predicate selection (where clause condition).

Case 1 - Order By

Now if your data in given field has specific order or your select query needs data in specific order 
eg- 
rank of employee order by their salary (i.e order by salary & band)
or 
order the employees based on joining date (i.e order by joining date)

then you need to save data / result using order by clause (to get total order) & we need to use order by (salary) so that whenever you query the target data you can get the required ordered data by default.

Case 2 - sort by

And if data in given field is not required in specific order like uniquely generated alphanumeric fields like Customer_id

In this case logically final data is not required to be present in specific order based on customer_id but since it's a unique key & mostly used in joining 
hence while we store the data for customer transaction details in each partition it needs to be present in sorted/ordered manner to make the join faster.
So, in this case we use sort by (customer_id) while storing final result.